# MySQL Join Query { How to get following Result }

Tags: mysql, join

Table 1

```
 +----------+
 |id | data |
 +----------+
 |1  | USRA |
 +----------+
 |4  | USRB |
 +----------+
```

Table 2

```
+----------+
|cid | mid |
+----------+
|1  |  4   |
+----------+
|4  |  1   |
+----------+
```

Result Table

```
+----------------------+
|table1_id | table2_id |
+----------------------+
|USRA      | USRB      |
+----------------------+
|USRB      | USRA      |
+----------------------+
```

Comment: You need to select `FROM` table2 and `INNER JOIN` table1 twice

Comment: Do the tables relate to each other in some way

Comment: can you help me with query

Comment: Table 2 is Related to Table 1, Consider Table 2 Columns as id from Table 1, I want to show 'data' column from Table 1 in Result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
 a.data,
 b.data
FROM
 Table1 a
INNER JOIN
 Table2 t2
ON a.id = t2.cid
INNER JOIN
 Table1 b
ON b.id = t2.mid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.data, t3.data
FROM tab1 t1, tab2 t2, tab1 t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.id
AND   t3.id = t2.mid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t3.data, t1.data
FROM a t1, b t2, a t3
WHERE t1.id = t2.cid
AND   t3.id = t2.mid
```

[image]